# When did English stop requiring capitalisation of non-proper nouns?

Tags: history, capitalization, historical-change

I was reading [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/278375/99654) which referenced a number of 18th century publications which capitalised their non-proper nouns:

In **1769**, in "[The Microscope made easy](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5KpjAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA25&dq=camera%20%22screen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEEQ6AEwA2oVChMI9I7t9_uvyAIVRH4aCh2XqwNd#v=onepage&q=camera%20%22screen%22&f=false)":

> "Mention having been often made of a Screen to throw the Images of
>   Objects on, it is proper to inform the Reader, that such a Screen is
>   usually composed of a Sheet of the largest Elephant Paper, strained on
>   a frame, which slides up or down, or turns about at Pleasure on a
>   round wooden Pillar, in the Manner of some Fire-screens. Larger
>   Screens are likewise made sometimes with several Sheets of the same
>   Paper pasted together on Cloth, and let down from the Ceiling with a
>   Roller, like a large Map"

**1742**, in [Micrographia Nova: Or, a New Treatise on the Microscope](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0PRbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA61&dq=camera%20screen&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAmoVChMIo8-i3v-vyAIVgXEUCh3mRgJT#v=onepage&q=camera%20screen&f=false)

> Thus if a lens of about 6, 8, or 10 Feet focal Distance, be fix'd in
>   the Scioptric Ball, then if the Sun shine strongly on the Objects
>   without, opposite to the Window, the Images of all will be distinctly
>   form'd on a Wall or large Sheet or Screen of white Paper placed in
>   the Focus of the Glass; the result of which will be a beautiful and
>   most perfect *Piece of Perspective*, if the Objects are Buildings,
>   *&c.* but Gardens, Fields, Meadows, Hills, Groves *&c.* present you with a most exquisite and inimitable *Landscape*

This is [still the case](http://german.about.com/library/weekly/aa020919b.htm) for the German language, but English lost this property somewhere between that time and now.

When did English stop requiring capitalisation of non-proper nouns?

Comment: When did English "require" anything??  It's always been pretty much up to the writer and/or typesetter.

Comment: @HotLicks Well, I could phrase it as "when did the rules of English grammar in that point in time stop requiring..." but it would be too long. Do you have a better alternative?

Comment: Not to long for the body of your question (which should be summarized in the first paragraph).